# SQL - Rows not exist as exist

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables. One with a list of users, one with items and one with relation between the users and the items. User can have an item (stat = 0/1) or can have a duplicate (dup = 0/1). If you click on the item's or the duplicate's button, it runs a query that adds or updates the row.

It looks like this:

```
| user | item_id | stat | dup |
| ---- | ------- | ---- | --- |
| 17   |   1     |  1   |  1  |
| 5    |   2     |  1   |  0  |
| 8    |   1     |  0   |  1  |
| 9    |   4     |  1   |  0  |
```

I compare these data who have an item what the other does not have and vica versa with this query:

```
SELECT t2.user_id,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t1.dup=1 AND t2.stat=0 THEN item_id END) `My Item List`,
       GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN t2.dup=1 AND t1.stat=0 THEN item_id END) `Item List`
FROM table3 t1
LEFT JOIN table3 t2 USING (item_id)
WHERE t1.user_id = @current_user
  AND t2.user_id <> @current_user
GROUP BY t2.user_id
```

My problem is I can only compare the rows if the user already clicked the button of the item at least once, so the row generated, but I need the stat=0 rows as well even if they are not existing.

After the code runs the table should look like this, so I can see the relations even if the user doesnt have (stat=0) that item:

```
| user | item_id | stat | dup |
| ---- | ------- | ---- | --- |
| 17   |   1     |  1   |  1  |
| 5    |   2     |  0   |  0  |
| 5    |   6     |  1   |  0  |
| 8    |   1     |  0   |  1  |
| 9    |   4     |  1   |  0  |
| 9    |   6     |  0   |  0  |
| 17   |   13    |  0   |  0  |
```

How can I integrate this to the query above?

My tables:

Table1

```
CREATE TABLE table1(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    user_name varchar(255),
);
```

Table 2

```
CREATE TABLE table2(
    id NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    item_no varchar(255),
    item_name varchar(255),
    item_group varchar(255)
);
```

Table 3

```
CREATE TABLE table3 (
  id int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  user_id int NOT NULL,
  item_id int NOT NULL,
  stat tinyint NOT NULL,
  dup tinyint NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (id),
  FOREIGN KEY (user_id) REFERENCES table1(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (item_id) REFERENCES table2(id)
);
```

Thank you!

Comment: Show us sample table data for all tables, and also the expected result. (I.e. a [mcve].)

Comment: Add sample data as INSERT INTO. Show desired output for your sample data..

Comment: updated with the output data i deisre

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What if you just grab all unique combinations of user and item_id, and then only map the combinations present and leave the rest as null? We can replace the null with 0.

Something like,

```
SELECT 
  all_combos.user, 
  all_combos.item_id, 
  COALESCE(T.stat, 0) AS stat, 
  COALESCE(T.dup) AS dup 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      user, 
      item_id 
    FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT user FROM table3) u, 
      (SELECT DISTINCT item_id FROM table3) i
  ) AS all_combos 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 T ON T.user = all_combos.user 
  AND T.item_id = all_combos.item_id
```

If you want to create combinations of users and items that might not have ever happened in table3, you can combine them by modifying the subqueries for `u` and `i`

```
SELECT 
  all_combos.user, 
  all_combos.item_id, 
  COALESCE(T.stat, 0) AS stat, 
  COALESCE(T.dup) AS dup 
FROM 
  (
    SELECT 
      user, 
      item_id 
    FROM 
      (SELECT DISTINCT id as user FROM table1) u, 
      (SELECT DISTINCT id as item_id FROM table2) i
  ) AS all_combos 
  LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 T ON T.user = all_combos.user 
  AND T.item_id = all_combos.item_id
```

Comment: it says the 'user' column is invalid in the 'field list'. how can i fix it?

Comment: Maybe its user_id?  You'll have to correct my SQL to your data - your result says USER but the table shows USERID so I dont know exactly how you got USER

Comment: it works! just one more thing: it only generates a row for every item and user if the item was clicked (got into the database). any way to list them without clicking on it?

Comment: @gibrish_diodo the u and i subqueries are where you want to focus.  if you change each of those to be unique users from another table (not table3) then you can get items and users directly no matter if they existed in table 3 or not.

Comment: like this? `(SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table1) u, (SELECT DISTINCT id FROM table2)` . if i do this its not gonna work, because both tables primary key is `id` and i cant separate then in `all_combos.id`

Comment: @gibrish_diodo i edited the answer above to give you that alternative. You just can alias the id so that all_combos doesnt have 2 columns with the same name.  And if you alias them to the same name as they are listed in table 3, you dont even have to change the join syntax

Comment: it works! thank you! i was stuck on this for months. thank you! now i have to merge these result to my other query.

Comment: i was wondering, this query generates the same data with same structure as table3. is it possible to run my comparing query on the result?

Comment: Sure, since we're already joining to table3, you can add a filter WHERE T.user IS NULL and that will show you only the "new" rows which we created that were not already in table3. Study up on LEFT OUTER JOIN and you will understand how that works